# Cast Asp.Net API methods return as HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In my attempt to learn and understand WebAPI I think I have learnt that returns from APIController methods are wrapped up into HttpResponseMessage.

You also have the option to create a new HttpResponseMessage and put your `List<Product>` inside it.

I am interested in testing headers for example and if I pass in a accept header with the below code I want to test for the content type returned in the response.

I know I can always return a HttpResponseMessage because strictly thats what its doing but I was just wondering if there was a way to either cast the response back from a controller method as a HttpResponseMessage without having to create a HttpServer/HttpConfiguration setup as shown [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/asp-net-web-api-integration-testing-with-in-memory-hosting/).

```
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();


        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/api/products");
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DefaultApi",
         routeTemplate: "{controller}"
            );

        var routeData = new HttpRouteData(route, new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "GetData" } });
        var controller = new GetDataController();
        controller.ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, request);
        controller.Request = request;
        controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;

        /************************* HELP!!!***************/
        // If Get returns List<Product> can I cast it as HttpResponseMessage??
        /************************************************/

        var result = controller.Get();

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal("application/json", result.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType);
```

Comment: Are you trying create an integration test by creating a standalone server and sending an actual HTTP request as Despertar suggests or are you creating a unit test to check your controller code directly?

Comment: Well I was hoping I could make it so that it can be called and get a valid HTTP response back without a HttpServer

Comment: You'll need a running instance of the controller then as Despertar is suggesting.

Comment: Because responses are only populated properly when invoked by a valid HTTP Request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller methods are not meant to be called directly like that. You have to send an HTTP request to get an HTTP response. Try using

```
HttpResponseMessage response = HttpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

Although if you are not hosting in IIS you would have to create an `HttpSelfHostServer` to host the controller inside the process so that it can listen for requests. This will show you how to do that, http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that controller methods are not meant to be called directly because in some cases you should call them however I want a HttpResponseMessage back but was wondering if that could be done without a HttpServer

Comment: Agree with Jon. You might want to unit test your controllers, and then this becomes an issue.